# Il servilismo mi ripugna - Il servilismo ripugna

Tags: grammar

È corretto dire

> Il servilismo *mi* ripugna.

?

O, come credo -- sebbene non sappia spiegarne la ragione --, il *mi* è incorretto lì?

Ho cercato qualcosa online per capire se 'ripugnare' fosse un verbo riflessivo e se tale circostanza assumesse rilievo al riguardo, ma, non solo non sono riuscito a trovare alcunché, ho ora anche le idee più confuse di prima.

Questo è un altro esempio che, apparentemente, può essere diversamente articolato:

> Tu *mi* ripugni, fai schifo!
>
> Tu sei ripugnante, fai schifo!
>
> Tu ripugni, fai schifo!

Se nella risposta cennate anche a questa terna sarei grato.

Answer (score 4):

Le diverse versioni, secondo me, sono tutte corrette ma cambia il significato:

> Il servilismo mi ripugna

indica che ripugna "a me", ma non dice nulla sul fatto che possa ripugnare altre persone.

> Il servilismo ripugna

ha invece un senso assoluto: qualsiasi persona è ripugnata dal servilismo.

Stessa cosa si può dire per le tre frasi:

> Tu mi ripugni, fai schifo!

indica che la persona a cui ci si rivolge ripugna "a me" e quindi che fa schifo a me. Niente viene detto riguardo a sensi di schifo o di ripugnanza per altre persone.

> Tu sei ripugnante, fai schifo!
>
> Tu ripugni, fai schifo!

ha invece un senso assoluto. Le due frasi hanno significato uguale e assoluto (se si guarda, cambia solo la costruzione: nella prima si usa il verbo e nella seconda si usa l'aggettivo corrispondente con il verbo essere mantenendo il presente, il tempo usato per indicare qualcosa di assoluto), indicando che il senso di schifo e ripugnanza vale per qualsiasi persona.

Come diceva DaG nella sua risposta, non è un problema di verbi riflessivi, ma di significato assoluto e relativo della frase.

Answer (score 3):

Sono due frasi dal significato differente.

"Mi ripugna" = ripugna a me, ma può non ripugnare ad altri (per es., *la trippa mi ripugna*).

"Ripugna" senza specifiche indica che l'oggetto ripugna (o si afferma che ripugni, o che *debba* ripugnare) **a tutti**, senza distinzione. Dal contesto, credo che tu abbia ragione e che il senso inteso dall'autore fosse «il servilismo ripugna a tutti».

Lo stesso si applica a "fare schifo".

Il verbo "ripugnare" originariamente significava «opporsi, resistere, fare resistenza»:

> *...questa è viscosità, che ripugna al moto per tutti i versi, e
>       quella è gravità, che ripugna al solo moto in su.* [Galileo Galilei, Dialogo sopra i Massimi Sistemi]

Answer (score 2):

Una qualsiasi [voce di dizionario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ripugnare/) ci rassicura sul fatto che “ripugnare” si costruisce con “a” (per esempio, «gli ripugna parlare della sua vita passata»). Nella voce che cito c'è anche un esempio con “mi”.

Quanto alla terna di frasi, la prima va senz'altro bene e la seconda pure (anche se non c'entra direttamente col resto del discorso).
La terza – così come anche «Il servilismo ripugna» – è ammissibile, anche se suona lievemente monca. Sarebbe come dire «Elberich piace», senza specificare a chi, quasi sottintendendo “piace a tutti, piace a chiunque lo conosca” o simili.

(I verbi riflessivi non c'entrano.)